# Binding both services and parameters with dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a service consuming a set of services implementing an interface `IX`:

```
   public class MyService()
   {
       MyService(IEnumerable<IX> xs)
       { 
          // Store xs in some field and later use them repeatedly. 
       }
   }
```

I want a number of instances of a class `MyX` implementing `IX`:

```
  public class MyX : IX
  {
    public string Field { get; }   
    public MyX(string field)
    {
      Field = field;
    }
  }
```

I add a number of these either as singletons:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IX>(new MyX("field value 1"));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IX>(new MyX("field value 2"));
```

**[UPDATE]** ... or from configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(configuration.GetSection("xs").Get<IEnumerable<MyX>>());
```

This implementation works as expected: My service now has an IEnumerable comprising the two distinct instances of `MyX`.

However, I need to add a logger to the `MyX` class. I try this:

```
 public class MyX : IX
  {
    ILogger<MyX> _logger;
    public string Field { get; }

    public X(ILogger<MyX> logger, string field)
    {
      _logger = logger;
      Field = field;
    }
  }
```

But now I cannot construct `MyX` during service setup, because I do not yet have a logger:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IX>(new MyX(/* But where would I get a logger? */, "field value 1"));
```

I've run into variants of this problem a number of times. In general, it feels like DI wants me to separate my classes into some form of multi-stage construction (first field, then later, at service resolution time, add the logger). That would entail separating `MyX` into a `MyXFactory` and a `MyX`, but that seems a bit awkward.

What's the right way to construct some number of instances of `MyX` for use with dependency injection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an override of `AddSingleton<T>` method which accepts a lambda builder where you can access the `ServiceProvider`.

So you can utilize it like below :

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<X>(buillder=> 
   new MyX(builder.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MyX>>(),"field 1");
});
```

Alternatively, you can build a singleton factory `IXFactory` that instantiates and returns the related `X` implementations.

---

As the question evolves :
Assuming you have access to the `IConfiguration` provided. You can have a configuration class something like below:

```
public class XConfig
{
   public string[] FieldValues { get; set; }
}
```

You can read your config into `XConfig` instance :

```
var config = Configuration.Get<XConfig>();
```

You may need a using `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;` for this.

Now you can use basic foreach to add a singleton instance for each `FieldValue`

```
foreach(var fieldValue in config.FieldValues){
  builder.Services.AddSingleton<X>(buillder=> 
     new MyX(builder.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MyX>>(),fieldValue);
  });
}
```

---

An alternate approach with a Factory approach and with the possibility of `FieldValues` changing (to give you an idea of edge cases, you can of course just use `IOptions<T>` to initiate the instances once)

```
    public class XFactory
    {
        private readonly object Sync = new();
        private readonly Dictionary<string, MyX> instances = new();
        private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

        public XFactory(IOptionsMonitor<XConfig> optionsMonitor, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            optionsMonitor.OnChange(this.OnConfigChange);
            this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider; 
        }

        private void OnConfigChange(XConfig config)
        {
            lock (Sync)
            {
                var itemsToRemove = instances.Keys.Where(r => !config.FieldValues.Contains(r)).ToList();
                itemsToRemove.ForEach(r => instances.Remove(r));

                foreach (var fieldValue in config.FieldValues)
                {
                    if (instances.ContainsKey(fieldValue))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var logger = this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MyX>>();

                    instances.Add(fieldValue, new MyX(logger, fieldValue));
                }
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<MyX> GetInstances()
        {
            return instances.Values;
        }
        
    }
```

And register this factory as a singleton :

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IXFactory,XFactory>();
```

Comment: It accepts an [implementation factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicecollectionserviceextensions-addsingleton-1(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-func((system-iserviceprovider-0)))) i.e. a function that returns an implementation instance.

Comment: Very good, thanks. However, how would I read in my `MyX` instances from configuration?

Comment: @SørenDebois can you elaborate on what your configuration looks like? like your configuration contains an array of values and you want to provide an instance?

Comment: @SørenDebois you can check the updated answer.

Comment: @Eldar thanks! The solution here is to move fields of `MyX` not initialized by DI into an auxiliary class `XConfig`. But that seems complex: I'm writing a library; users of the library now have to understand two classes (`MyX`, `XConfig`) and how they relate, instead of just one. I can't decide whether I'm right in worrying ("obviously, the class MyX shouldn't be split up just to fit the arbitrary constraints of the DI framework") or whether I'm being overzealous ("obviously, you can split a class into its construction parameters and the class itself; who cares?"). I'd appreciate a comment?

Comment: @SørenDebois I would pick the split route this would give me more flexibility on what to do with the configuration

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-activatorutilities-createinstance-1(system-iserviceprovider-system-object())), which allows the resolution of parameters not registered with the DI container:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IX>(
    sericeProvider => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyX>(
        serviceProvider,
        new object[] { "field value 1" }));
```

This will allow `MyX` to be instantiated with any number of dependencies, as long as there is only one of type `string`.